# SQL Query for conditional selecting

Tags: sql

I have a question about how to retrieve data from one customer's order table (Oracle) like this:

```
id   customer cake          top   
1    001      chocolate     cream
2    002      chocolate     jam
3    002      vanilla       cream
4    003      banana        cream
```

I want to know all orders from customers whose order includes chocolate cake.

The right result should be

```
id   customer cake          top   
1    001      chocolate     cream
2    002      chocolate     jam
3    002      vanilla       cream
```

I could do this by 2 separate queries in SQL, but is there any way to do this in a single query?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

you should use an sub-query to get the customers:

```
select * from order where customer in (
  select distinct customer from order where cake = 'chocolate'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A subquery that selects the distinct customers whose order include chocolate would work :

```
select 
  * 
from 
  order 
where 
  customer 
in (select 
      distinct customer 
    from 
      order 
    where 
      cake = 'chocolate')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using inner queries.

```
SELECT * FROM ORDER WHERE CUSTOMER IN (
    SELECT CUSTOMER FROM ORDER WHERE cake = 'chocolate'
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM order_details
              WHERE customers.id = order_details.customer_id
              AND cake = 'chocolate');
```

Edited: added the chocolate cake condition.

Comment: SELECT 1 will select 1, I suspect you meant SELECT TOP 1?

Comment: @wentimo No, I dont mean top 1.  The way i wrote it will select 1, yes.  but that is enough to locate the row and prove its existence.  since we don't need any fields from the Exists clause, using a 1 in place of * makes it runs faster and does the same thing.

Comment: Ah nifty, I didn't know about this particular pattern as a solution. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ORDER O1 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL FROM ORDER O2 WHERE O1.ID = O2.ID AND cake = 'chocolate'
 )
```

You may try a variation of this subquery.